# Emit an action after dispatch returns in NGRX/Redux

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have the following code in my Angular app:

```
if(employee.details == undefined)
{
   this.store$.dispatch(new LoadEmployeeAction({ emp: action.id }));
}

this.empAction.emit(data)
```

How do I prevent/stop my emit function from running till after my dispatch (which performs a get from a web api) returns, since it updates the value of data in the store?